# Preventing validator from firing after bound value changes

Tags: apache-flex

I am working on a product options form whose contents should be cleared by a clearOptions() method each time the user adds an option.  The option name TextInput is bound to a value object that is reinstantiated each time the the user adds a product option.  The problem I am having is that the StringValidator fires each time the bound value object is reinstantiated.

```
<mx:StringValidator id="valOptionName" minLength="1" source="{txtOptionName}" property="text" trigger="{btnAddChangeOption}" triggerEvent="click"/>

<mx:TextInput id="txtOptionName" width="120" text="{currentProductOption.name}"/>

<mx:LinkButton id="btnAddChangeOption" label="Add/Change Option" click="saveUpdateOption(event)" horizontalCenter="0"/>
```

The following code is what causes the StringValidator to fire when it shouldn't.  It results in a red outline around a text box.

```
private function clearOptions():void
{
    currentProductOption = new ProductOptionVO();
}
```

Thank you for any help,

Orville

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting the source of the validator manually in the validation code and then switching it off before currentProductOption is reinstantiated.